# Integrity constraint violation foreign key constraint fails

Tags: foreign-keys, laravel-5

> ERROR - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`assign_project`, CONSTRAINT `assign_project_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`assigned_to`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)) (SQL: insert into `assign_project` (`project_id`, `description`, `work_start_date`, `work_end_date`, `assign_status`, `assigned_by`, `assigned_to`) values (1, xyz, 2016-09-02, 2016-11-02, 1, 1, ))

User Model

```
<?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class User extends Model
 {

  protected $fillable = ["user_id","company_id","first_name","last_name","email","password","confirm_password","phone_number","address","pincode","role_id","user_status"]; 

 }
?>
```

in Controller

```
public function getassignprojectemployee(Request $Request){

  $data = Request::all();
    $input = DB::table('usi_assign_project')
    ->insert($data);

    if($input > 0){
        return Redirect::to('admin_assign_projects_employee');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin_assign_project');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like your $assigned_to is empty? Check your $data and make sure $assigned_to is there.

Comment: @SteD i didnt see that all this time. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove foreign relation on your Model and try again.